# Parametric Equalizer GUI in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, math, graphics

I need to write a Parametric Equalizer like this one:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/screenshots/2218/original.jpg

Do you know a way to realize this kind of graphic control in C# using WPF? What I mean is: do you know the mathematics rules that connect the points in a Parametric Equalizer?

Comment: could you please share your data models or any other research you've made for the same?

Comment: there is a Chart control, have you tried that?

Comment: I don't have any data model at the moment. I'm starting to write the code but I have no idea about the math laws that rules the curve painting method.

Comment: @cjb110 Chart Control? Hmm...can you please post any example?

Comment: There are no chart control in "plain" WPF. Also, you might be better of drawing the geometry yourself instead of trying to fit your equalizer into a chart because of the added requirements of the equalizer.

Comment: there are many ways to draw such chart in WPF, but before anything else you need to workout and invest your time to research for the same.

Comment: I searched on the web, but I didn't find nothing that explain how to link the point on a paramtric eq. For this reason I'm asking to the community.

Comment: Closed. see my answer in the duplicated question which includes full source code. Just change the straight lines for curved ones.

Comment: Nice work, but your answer has nothing to do with my question! Have you ever seen/used a Parametric Equalizer? The point are not connected with lines, but using log functions depending on the type of the filter. Reopen the question, please.

Comment: I agree that this question is not a duplicate, but your question is too broad to get an answer and should probably be closed anyway. To get you started I suggest that you learn about WPF geometry. You can use a `Canvas` as the container for the line represented by a `Path`. You can use an appropriate shape for the handles. The position of the elements can be bound to a view-model. Things get more complicated when you want to interact with the handles and if you want a variable number of handles or a fluid layout. Ask more specific questions about this and you may get answers.

Comment: Thank you Martin for your interest. I already have a good knowledge about WPF, MVVM pattern, and all the .NET tools needed to do something similiar. All I need to know is the math rule that allow to draw the line that connect the point. Is this a question for the stack overflow group or is maybe a question for a mathematic group?